# Unable to run my app in Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I've updated my expo version to latest. But after that I'm unable to run the app in my phone. LAN is not working, tunnel not working and also local as well.

> Something went wrong

Comment: facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `expo r -c` and reset your expo cache

Comment: clear your npm cache by ```npm cache clear --force``` or try restarting your pc.